# What is the correct sentence to express the relationship between the user and his direct manager:

Tags: foreign-key, many-to-many

What is the correct sentence to express the relationship between the user and his direct manager:

1. A many-to-many table must be maintained because managers have several employees under them.
2. A field of type reference (foreign key) must be added to the users table with a reference to the record of his direct manager.
3. There is no need to add anything because a manager is also an employee, so we will use the inheritance mechanism.
4. Neither answer is correct.

I think the 2nd option is the correct sentence because it suggests using a field of type reference (foreign key) in the users table to establish a direct relationship between a user and their manager

Comment: Which option do _you_ think is correct, and why?

Comment: @mustaccio The 2nd option because it suggests using a field of type reference (foreign key) in the users table to establish a direct relationship between a user and their manager

Comment: You should add that to the question.

Comment: @mustaccio I added

Comment: Is this an assignment ?  The relationship can be different in different companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your actual question seems to be, "how can I be confident that my answer is correct?"

You have a working hypothesis, which doesn't seem wrong at the first glance: a reference to the manager's record does allow you to express the user-manager relationship. Now you have to consider other answers to see if they might be even better.

- The "many-to-many table" option seems wrong: although it's true that "managers have several employees under them", this option also suggests that employees might have several managers above them, which is most likely false.
- The "inheritance mechanism" option doesn't look right either: inheritance may exist between *entities* (i.e. the "manager" entity has the same attributes as a "user" entity, plus some attributes specific only to managers), but it cannot exist between *instances* of such entities (i.e. a particular manager does not have the same attribute *values* as any of their subordinate employees).

Since we have two apparently incorrect answers and one plausible answer, the fourth option also seems wrong, and you're left with a single option.